# lochalhost:8080 does not display Centos 8 Tomcat SpringBoot server contents

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, vagrant, vagrantfile, centos8

As part of a local deployment of a GitHub project using a Centos 8 Vagrant virtual machine, I have obtained the following results after running "vagrant up" in GitBash:

Virtual machine log:

```
  default:
default:               |\      _,,,--,,_
default:              /,`.-'`'   ._  \-;;,_
default:   _______ __|,4-  ) )_   .;.(__`'-'__     ___ __    _ ___ _______
default:  |       | '---''(_/._)-'(_\_)   |   |   |   |  |  | |   |       |
default:  |    _  |    ___|_     _|       |   |   |   |   |_| |   |       | __ _ _
default:  |   |_| |   |___  |   | |       |   |   |   |       |   |       | \ \ \ \
default:  |    ___|    ___| |   | |      _|   |___|   |  _    |   |      _|  \ \ \ \
default:  |   |   |   |___  |   | |     |_|       |   | | |   |   |     |_    ) ) ) )
default:  |___|   |_______| |___| |_______|_______|___|_|  |__|___|_______|  / / / /
default:  ==================================================================/_/_/_/
default:
default: :: Built with Spring Boot :: 2.4.5
default:
default: 2021-08-09 00:25:52.606  INFO 27111 --- [           main] o.s.s.petclinic.PetClinicApplication     : Starting PetClinicApplication v2.4.5 using Java 1.8.0_302 on localhost.localdomain with PID 27111 (/home/vagrant/spring-petclinic/target/spring-petclinic-2.4.5.jar started by vagrant in /home/vagrant/spring-petclinic)
default: 2021-08-09 00:25:52.624  INFO 27111 --- [           main] o.s.s.petclinic.PetClinicApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
default: 2021-08-09 00:25:54.610  INFO 27111 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
default: 2021-08-09 00:25:54.696  INFO 27111 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 76 ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
default: 2021-08-09 00:25:55.664  INFO 27111 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
default: 2021-08-09 00:25:55.685  INFO 27111 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
default: 2021-08-09 00:25:55.685  INFO 27111 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.45]
default: 2021-08-09 00:25:55.885  INFO 27111 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
default: 2021-08-09 00:25:55.886  INFO 27111 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3152 ms
default: 2021-08-09 00:25:56.535  INFO 27111 --- [           main] org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager          : Cache 'vets' created in EhcacheManager.
default: 2021-08-09 00:25:56.552  INFO 27111 --- [           main] org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107CacheManager     : Registering Ehcache MBean javax.cache:type=CacheStatistics,CacheManager=urn.X-ehcache.jsr107-default-config,Cache=vets
default: 2021-08-09 00:25:56.563  INFO 27111 --- [           main] org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107CacheManager     : Registering Ehcache MBean javax.cache:type=CacheStatistics,CacheManager=urn.X-ehcache.jsr107-default-config,Cache=vets
default: 2021-08-09 00:25:56.672  INFO 27111 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
default: 2021-08-09 00:25:56.950  INFO 27111 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
default: 2021-08-09 00:25:57.220  INFO 27111 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
default: 2021-08-09 00:25:57.324  INFO 27111 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.30.Final
default: 2021-08-09 00:25:57.493  INFO 27111 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
default: 2021-08-09 00:25:57.655  INFO 27111 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
default: 2021-08-09 00:25:58.813  INFO 27111 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
default: 2021-08-09 00:25:58.826  INFO 27111 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
default: 2021-08-09 00:25:59.968  INFO 27111 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
default: 2021-08-09 00:26:01.442  INFO 27111 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 13 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
default: 2021-08-09 00:26:01.533  INFO 27111 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
default: 2021-08-09 00:26:01.568  INFO 27111 --- [           main] o.s.s.petclinic.PetClinicApplication     : Started PetClinicApplication in 9.688 seconds (JVM running for 10.503)
```

Vagrant file:

```
    Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "centos/8"

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "rsync"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8443, host: 8080

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "4096"
    vb.cpus = "2"
  end

  config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, inline: <<-SHELL

    echo "whoami..."
    whoami

    echo "pwd..."
    pwd

    # echo "upgrading..."
    # sudo yum upgrade -y

    echo "installing unzip..."
    sudo yum install unzip -y

    echo "installing git..."
    sudo yum install git -y

    echo "installing mysql..."

    sudo dnf install mysql-server -y

    sudo systemctl enable mysqld

    sudo systemctl start mysqld.service

    sudo systemctl status mysqld



    echo "installing java..."

    sudo yum install java-11-openjdk-devel -y


    sudo yum install maven -y


    git clone https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic.git
    sleep 30

    cd spring-petclinic

    echo "running project jar"
    ./mvnw package
    java -jar target/*.jar




  SHELL

end
```

As shown, the Tomcat server seems to be running on the correct port without obvious errors. However, upon entering http://localhost:8080/ (the correct address of entry) into my Chrome search bar, I get an error screen with the following message:

> This page isn’t working

> localhost didn’t send any data.

> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

The site uses an H2 in-memory database which can typically be accessed by navigating to http://localhost:8080/h2-console, but this doesn't work and produces the same error.

I tried running another application on port 8080 afterwards, and was able to confirm that port 8080 was indeed in use by my initial webapp as the second one did not run and produced an error.

Assuming there is nothing wrong with the source GitHub project (which I can confidently claim there is not), what have I done incorrectly to cause this issue, and how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

In the log it show `Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path` but you are connecting 8080 on the host to port 8443 on the guest.

Try changing the target port on the guest to 8080 as well. See [vagrant forwarded ports](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports)

```
 config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
```

The whole concept of running a server in the vagrant shell seems very odd. I assume it is just some quick and very dirty test. Better look at using something like ansible for configuring you guests.